# dynamic MenuContribution - Get a warning

Tags: eclipse, plugins, warnings

I am using dynamic `MenuContribution` and get a warning that two of my referenced identifiers "cannot be found". Even though the contribution works. These warnings bug me.

I have a `CompoundContributionItem` implementation defined in one of my plugins. Basically it looks like this:

```
public class ViewerHistoryMenuItems extends CompoundContributionItem
    implements IExecutableExtension { 

    private static final String PARAM_TYPE = "type";
    private static final String PARAM_COMMAND = "command";

    // some fields

    public void setInitializationData(final IConfigurationElement config,
            final String propertyName, final Object data) {
        /* set fields */
    }

    protected final IContributionItem[] getContributionItems() {
        /* create Items */ 
    }
}
```

In other plugins I use this `ContributionItem` implementation by declaring the following:

```
<menuContribution locationURI="menu:mylocationUri">
    <dynamic id="myId">
        <class class="ViewerHistoryMenuItems">
            <parameter
                     name="type"
                     value="someValue">
            </parameter>
            <parameter
                     name="command"
                     value="someCommandId">
            </parameter>
        </class>
    </dynamic>
    <command
        commandId="someCommandId"
        icon="anIcon.png">
    </command>
</menuContribution>
```

When looking at the Problems-View I get two entries there (for each plug-in, which uses this contribution):

```
**Referenced identifier 'type' in attribute 'name' cannot be found**

**Referenced identifier 'command' in attribute 'name' cannot be found**
```

What am I missing here? Any ideas, why I get this warning?

PS: It doesn't help, to make the two fields `PARAM_TYPE` & `PARAM_COMMAND` public

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think this is related to the presence of internal fields within a class.

If you look at a similar error (not the same since it includes `annotationType`), the correction involved the *definition* of said Referenced identifier:

```
Referenced identifier 'com.atlassian.connector.eclipse.cruicible.ui.comment.annotation' 
in attribute 'annotationType' cannot be found
```

Fixed with:

```
+   <extension
+         point="org.eclipse.ui.editors.annotationTypes">
+      <type
+            markerType="com.atlassian.connector.eclipse.crucible.ui.com.atlassian.connector.eclipse.cruicible.ui.comment.marker"
+            name="com.atlassian.connector.eclipse.cruicible.ui.comment.annotation">
+      </type>
+   </extension>
+   <extension
+         id="com.atlassian.connector.eclipse.cruicible.ui.comment.marker"
+         point="org.eclipse.core.resources.markers">
+   </extension>
```

Considering the [extension point `org.eclipse.ui.menus` help page](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_menus.html):

```
<!ELEMENT parameter  EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST parameter
  name  IDREF #REQUIRED
  value CDATA #REQUIRED
>
```

> A parameter to either an executable extension or a command -- depending on where it appears in the extension.
>
> - **name** - The name is either the name of the parameter to pass to the executable extension, or the identifier of the parameter for the command.
> - **value** - The value to pass for this parameter.

You need to reference in the name attribute an id present somewhere else in your `plugin.xml`.

Comment: It says "The name is either the name of the parameter..." So I think I used that, and called one parameter "type" and the other "command". But I guess, I have to think more about your profound answer, VonC.

Comment: @pimpf0r: that's just it: I am not sure "name of the parameter" can reference any *internal* field class. In a declarative mode such as a `plugin.xml`, I would expect the parameter being defined elsewhere within said `plugin.xml`

Comment: Okay, I think I found "elsewhere". Elsewhere in this case means: The location where the referenced command is defined/declared. I was referring within my dynamic declaration to a command within the same plugin.xml. But the added Parameter weren't declared there. 

Thanks for your help, VonC. *high5*

Comment: @pimpf0r: thank you for this feedback. Could you post as an answer what you needed to add to your `plugin.xml` to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Sure thing, VonC. Here we go:

Within the dynamic declaration (see above) there are two parameter references

```
<parameter
  name="type"
  value="someValue">
</parameter>
<parameter
  name="command"
  value="someCommandId">
</parameter>
```

These two parameter are meant to be passed to the command itself. The command declaration is within the same *plugin.xml* but **wasn't** declaring these two commandParameters.

What I did was adding these missing commandParameters, resolving the missing reference, which was clearly stated by the warning.

```
<command
  categoryId="aCategory"
               id="someCommandId"
               name="%theName">
  <commandParameter
    id="type"
    name="type"/>
  <commandParameter
    id="command"
    name="command">
  </commandParameter>
</command>
```

So, you were absolutely right by saying "*the correction involved the definition of said reference identifier*". The question just was **where** and **what** I had to define.
I think, I wasn't thinking about the most obvious in this case.