# How do I suppress eclipse warning: Referenced identifier 'VIEWNAME:secondaryid' in attribute 'id' cannot be found

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-pde

In eclipse 3.4, here is the section of my plugin.xml:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.views">
  <view
    allowMultiple="true"
    class="the.full.class.name"
    icon="images/icon.gif"
    id="VIEWNAME"
    name="View Name">
  </view>
</extension>
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions">
  <perspectiveExtension targetID="MY_PERSPECTIVE_ID">
     <view
        closeable="false"
        id="VIEWNAME:secondaryid"
        minimized="false"
        moveable="false"
        ratio=".75"
        relationship="left"
        relative="org.eclipse.ui.editorss"
        showTitle="true"
        standalone="true"
        visible="true">
      </view>
    </perspectiveExtension>
  </extension>
```

The application works fine, I just can't get rid of that annoying warning!

Comment: is this similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279511/dynamic-menucontribution-get-a-warning (in term of the general issue)?

Comment: But the view is declared, and if I change the view id to be VIEWNAME:secondaryid, then it fails to create the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be hitting this bug
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=287551

Answer (score 0):

the

```
perspectiveExtensions
```

extension point expects the actual view ID. Since in your case it is 'VIEWNAME' therefore for

```
perspectiveExtensions
```

id field use the same.

After doing this reset your eclipse perpective and open it again.

Comment: And then the application doesn't work, because the secondary id is not specified correctly.  I don't want any instance of this view in the perspective, but a specific instance of it.